# How to specify form parameter when using webclient to upload file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As title, how to specify additional form parameters when uploading file using webclient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this with a `WebClient`. You will need to manually generate the `multipart/form-data` request. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274968/send-multipart-form-data-content-type-request/3275002#3275002) which could be easily adapted. You will just need to insert the file contents at the parameter you like. In this example I used a `StreamWriter` but if your file is binary you would probably want to directly write to the request stream.

The idea is to achieve [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html).

If you don't want to go this route and those values are not very big you could probably pass the additional parameters at the request string and continue using `UploadFile` method. Of course the target url must be capable of reading those values from the query string.

Comment: too bad to hear that weblcient's limitation on this. Is there any thrid party library to get this done?

Comment: @user496949, I've blogged about a sample implementation: http://www.bratched.com/en/component/content/article/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Can you see this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295877/webclient-too-many-automatic-redirections-were-attempted