# Send form-data using HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, form-data, rest, zoho

I'm trying to make an API call to third party URL, which is working fine through postman, but same request through C# HttpClient not working.

> **This is how I'm sending request in postman**

[image]

> **C# Sample Code**

```
 var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
 nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PARAM1", "PARAM1 Value"));
 nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PARAM2", "PARAM2 Value"));
 nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PARAM3", "PARAM3 Value"));
  var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "Https://ThirdPartyURL") { 
                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) 
            };
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

**UPDATE #1:**
**

> **Fiddler Traces for postman request(which is working fine)**

[image]

> **Fiddler Traces for C# Request(which is failing)**
> [image]

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Moksh

Comment: I see you're using `FormUrlEncodedContent` and in Postman is selected `form-data`.  `FormUrlEncodedContent` sends `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; <charset>` and form-data I believe should be `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<value>`

Comment: @dcg looks like that's the real issue, I just verified fiddler traces for both postman and C# and found same thing, Do you have sample code like how can we set content-type here ?

Comment: I was just taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275002/4152153) answer, I think it may help you.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53190314/4152153). There's `MultipartFormDataContent` class.

Comment: @dcg well, Earlier I tried `MultipartFormDataContent` but that was throwing 400 bad request.

Comment: @dcg No luck with other link as well, same 400 bad request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225542/discussion-between-mox-shah-and-dcg).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

try to create a new class:

```
public class RecipientSender
{
public string Recipient_First_Name {get; set;}
public string Recipient_Last_Name {get; set;}
.....
}
```

and create httpclientrequest like this:

```
....
....

var recipientSender=new RecipientSender { Recipient_FirstName=..., }
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
var stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recipientSender);
contentData = new StringContent(stringData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var httpResponseMessage=client.PostAsync(url, contentData);
.....
```