# Regex to extract boundary and content type out of Mail headers

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using a parsing service and we get the following headers string when an email is received:

```
Message-ID: <4f2c2c98.1007650a.68f6.ffff9ed6@mx.google.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_00EB_01CCE26A.183F8AD0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0
```

Unfortunately i'm weak at regex and wondering how to extract the boundary and content type to end up with just:

```
[:content_type] => multipart/mixed
[:boundary] => ----=_NextPart_000_00EB_01CCE26A.183F8AD0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match the text:

`/Type:\s{0,}(.*?);\sboundary=\"(.*?)\"/`

Note the two capture groups for the data you want.

Comment: This worked until i added a space after `\s` because sometimes there's multiple spaces. Thanks!

Comment: I think there should be also multiple-space control right before boundary=

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the allowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147467/4863726) the regex would be something like this.

```
boundary=\"?([a-zA-Z0-9'\(\)+_,-.\/:=? ]*)(?<! )\"?
```