# How do I send a HTTP POST value to a (PHP) page using Python?

Tags: php, python, post

I have a PHP page that has 1 textbox and when I press on the submit button. My SQL is going to store this product name into my database. My question is; is it possible to send/post the product name using Python script that asks for 1 value and then use my PHP page to send it to my database? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-anyway-to-do-http-put-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393738/programmatic-form-submit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571083/in-python-how-might-one-log-in-answer-a-web-form-via-http-post-not-url-encoded

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150517/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script

Comment: @S.Lott: Sending a file is different, because it's typically form/multipart data. I'd say this question is legit. Perhaps too much so to quit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the urllib and urllib2 modules.

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

Simply create a Request object with the needed data. Then read the response from your PHP service.

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request

Answer (score 3):

When testing, or automating websites using python, I enjoy using twill. Twill is a tool that automatically handles cookies and can read HTML forms and submit them.

For instance, if you had a form on a webpage you could conceivably use the following code:

```
from twill import commands
commands.go('http://example.com/create_product')
commands.formvalue('formname', 'product', 'new value')
commands.submit()
```

This would load the form, fill in the value, and submit it.

Comment: While twill is really convenient for testing scripts, it is somewhat broken in 2 ways.
1) Must parse HTML before it could post.
2) Cannot always handle invalid HTML without crashing.

Comment: "Doesn't work with forms that don't exist or are invalid" are two things that I don't care about. This is not a 'broken' thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) is a nice Python way to form/send HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

I find http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml to be a good source of information about urllib2, which is probably the best tool for the job.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

The encoding is actually done using urllib, and this supports HTTP POST. There is also a way to use GET, where you have to pass the data into urlencode.

Don't forget to call read() though, otherwise the request won't be completed.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i prefer to use **Requests**. As its summary, this is a *HTTP library for Python, built for human beings*.

To quickly solve problems, rather than study deeply in HTTP, **Requests** will be a better choice. (Yeah, i mean compared to *urllib* or *socket*)

For example,
A python file which send a POST request with userdata:

```
import requests
userdata = {"firstname": "Smith", "lastname": "Ayasaki", "password": "123456"}
resp = requests.post('http://example.com/test.php', data = userdata)
```

And the following text.php treating this request:

```
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["lastname"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
echo "FIRSTNAME: $firstname  LASTNAME: $lastname  PW: $password";
```

Finally, the response text (resp.content in python) will be like:

> FIRSTNAME: Smith  LASTNAME: Ayasaki  PW: 123456

- A simple Quickstart: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/
- Another answer recommending **Requests**: [Sending data using POST in Python to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214231/sending-data-using-post-in-python-to-php/29492097#29492097)

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to [@antileet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629518/how-do-i-send-a-http-post-value-to-a-php-page-using-python/632312#632312)'s procedure, it works similarly if you're trying to do a HTTP POST request with a web-service-like payload, except you just omit the urlencode step; i.e.

```
import urllib, urllib2

payload = """
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<web_service_request>
    <short_order>Spam</short_order>
    <short_order>Eggs</short_order>
</web_service_request>
""".strip()
query_string_values = {'test': 1}
uri = 'http://example.com'

# You can still encode values in the query string, even though
# it's a POST request. Nice to have this when your payload is
# a chunk of text.
if query_string_values:
    uri = ''.join([uri, '/?', urllib.urlencode(query_string_values)])
req = urllib2.Request(uri, data=payload)
assert req.get_method() == 'POST'
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print 'Response:', response.read()
```