# Sending data using POST in Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, urllib2

PHP code:

```
<?php
$data=$_POST['data'];
echo $data;
?>
```

When I do that, the HTML page that Python prints notifies me that PHP
did not receive any value in `$data` I.e:

> Error in $name; undefined index

However, when I send the data as GET (`http://localhost/mine.php?data=data`) and change the PHP method from POST to GET (`$data=$_GET['data']`), the value is gotten and processed.

My main issue here is that it seems the value in data does not go through to PHP as I would have wanted to use POST. What could be wrong?

Comment: Given that most of us are not clairvoyant, it may be a good idea to post your code.

Answer (score 34):

Look at this python:

```
import urllib2, urllib
mydata=[('one','1'),('two','2')]    #The first is the var name the second is the value
mydata=urllib.urlencode(mydata)
path='http://localhost/new.php'    #the url you want to POST to
req=urllib2.Request(path, mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print page
```

Almost everything was right there Look at line 2

heres the PHP:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['one'];
echo $_POST['two'];
?>
```

this should give you

```
1
2
```

Good luck and I hope this helps others

Answer (score 6):

There are plenty articles out there which suggest using **requests** rather then **Urllib** and **urllib2**. (Read References for more Information, the solution first)

Your Python-File (test.php):

```
import requests
userdata = {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "password": "jdoe123"}
resp = requests.post('http://yourserver.de/test.php', params=userdata)
```

Your PHP-File:

```
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["lastname"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_GET["password"]);
echo "firstname: $firstname lastname: $lastname password: $password";
```

> firstname: John lastname: Doe password: jdoe123

**References:**

1) [Good Article, why you should use requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

2) [What are the differences between the urllib, urllib2, and requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests)

Answer (score 5):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

params = urllib.urlencode(parameters) # parameters is dicitonar
req = urllib2.Request(PP_URL, params) # PP_URL is the destionation URL
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

looking arround I only found this post, it was a start point but I had to search a lot to update it, I like to post an update for the TheBestJohn's answer because he send the original one.

note: the php is the same

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

mydata=[('one','128'),('two','247')]
mydata=urllib.parse.urlencode(mydata)
utf8 = bytes(mydata, 'utf-8')
path='http://localhost/new.php'
page=urllib.request.urlopen(path, utf8, 300).read()
print(page)
```