# sending the json data from python to php

Tags: php, python, json

I am sending the json data from a python program using the below code

```
import json
import requests

data = {"temp_value":132}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
payload = {'json_playload': data_json}
r = requests.get('http://localhost/json1/js2.php',data=payload)
```

and receiving it in a php server side using the below code.

```
<?php

if($_GET['temp_value']) {
    $temp_value = $_GET['temp_value'];
    echo $temp_value;

  #  $data = array($id, $description);
   $arr=json_decode($temp_value,true);

   } else {
echo "not found";}
// Connect to MySQL
    include("dbconnect.php");

    // Prepare the SQL statement
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO test1.temperature1 (temp_value) VALUES ('$arr')";    

    // Execute SQL statement
    mysqli_query($dbh,$SQL);
    Echo "<a href=http://localhost/json1/review_data.php><center><u><b><h1>Manage values<h1><b><u></center></a>"

?>
```

along with the json data I have implemented like Id,time and date also gets updated in the database when i send the data.But what is happening here is like whenever i send the data from the python program it won't give any errors,when i see in the database and in the php page only 0(zero) values are inserted in both,however time and id gets updated.please someone suggest me a proper code and way.

Comment: In insert statement, what value u are getting in database.

Comment: zero.When i send the data from python and checked in the database only zero values are stored,not the actual values i sent.

Comment: Please check, whate u are getting in `$arr`.

Comment: try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214231/sending-data-using-post-in-python-to-php

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: temp_value in C:\wamp\www\json1\js2.php on line 3                                                              not found,when i commented the database part and just tried to get that temp_value in $arr

Comment: Add this line in php. echo $_GET['payload'];  & check what u are getting in

Comment: same error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import requests

data = {"temp_value":132}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
payload = {'json_playload': data_json}
r = requests.get('http://localhost/json1/js2.php',data=payload)
print(r.url)//http://localhost/json1/js2.php
```

Json data is not passed in to php.Check your python code

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2[]': ['value2', 'value3']}
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
print(r.url)
```

Result:
    http://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&key2%5B%5D=value2&key2%5B%5D=value3

You have to use like 
    payload = {"temp_value":132}

Comment: i have tried all the ways listed here,but no way has worked me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $json_payload = json_decode($_GET['json_payload']);
  $temp_value   = $json_payload['temp_value'];
?>
```

When you do this:

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost/json1/js2.php',data=payload)
```

You are sending a get request containing a JSON string representation of your data:

```
'{"temp_value": 132}'
```

stored in the get parameter named `json_payload`.

Therefore, on the client side, you must retrieve the contents of the `json_payload` parameter and decode the JSON string therein in order to retrieve `temp_value`.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
payload = {"temp_value":132}
r = requests.get('http://localhost/json1/js2.php',data=payload)
```

And leave your PHP code unmodified.