# SSL3 POST with Python

Tags: python, http, post, ssl, urllib2

I have a pile of tasks to automate within cPanel. There is a cPanel API described at http://videos.cpanel.net/cpanel-api-automation/ but I tried what I thought was easier for me...

Based on an answer from skyronic at [How do I send a HTTP POST value to a (PHP) page using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629518/how-do-i-send-a-http-post-value-to-a-php-page-using-python) I tried

```
import urllib, urllib2, ssl
url = 'https://mysite.com:2083/login'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 meridia (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)' 
values = {'name':cpaneluser,
          'pass':cpanelpw}
headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data,headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
```

The call to `urlopen()` is raising `NameError: global name 'HTTPSConnectionV3' is not defined`.

So then based on http://bugs.python.org/issue11220 I tried preceding the code above with

```
import httplib
class HTTPSConnectionV3(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self):
        sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self.sock = sock
            self._tunnel()
        try:
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, \
                                        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)
        except ssl.SSLError, e:
            print("Trying SSLv3.")
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, \
                                        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

class HTTPSHandlerV3(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def https_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(HTTPSConnectionV3, req)

urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSHandlerV3()))
```

This does print the "Trying SSLv3" and raises `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol>`

And finally that led me to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/606 where gregakespret who say he solved a similar problem using a solution from Senthil Kuaran at http://bugs.python.org/issue11220 :

```
https_sslv3_handler = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3))
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(https_sslv3_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

But that raises `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'`. And indeed `help(urllib)` doesn't include any mention of request, and `import urllib.request` results in `No module named request`.

I'm using Python 2.7.3 within the Enthought Canopy distribution. The cPanel site is using a self-signed certificate, which I  mention since it'sa an irregularity that would trip up a regular browser, though I gather that urllib and urllib2 don't actually authenticate the certificate anyway.

Thank you for reading, more so if you have a suggestion or can help me understand the problem.

Comment: `urllib` does not have `HTTPSHandler`. Refer to [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html). You can use `urllib2` instead. Check [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPSHandler)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the requests library.

I'm the OP and it's been a while since I posted this. I've solved other related tasks (POST to use Instructure's Canvas API) using the requests library and found that code that had worked with urllib/urllib2 is now much shorter and sweeter.

Someone just upvoted this question, causing me to see that noone had answered it. My answer isn't much of one to my OP, but it is the direction I'd advise, having solved related problems since the post.

As for this question, I solved the problem by scripting in BASH on the server that had cPanel running. It was just a matter of identifying which cPanel scripts to call. But I did not get it running through the cPanel Web API.