# How to send binary file via REST in Python?

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to upload a PDF file for docstoc but I haven't got any luck. I've tried the [restclient](http://github.com/thraxil/restclient/) library for python but I have no idead how to upload/send a binary file lika a PDF. Could you guys provide examples on how to do this? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that is has been asked before. The idea is treat PDF as another file, but send the file as multipart/form-data. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264300/http-post-binary-files-using-python-concise-non-pycurl-examples/1264540#1264540) here points you to two recipes which can be used to accomplish this.