# Generate a random letter in Python

Tags: python, random, python-3.x

Is there a way to generate random letters in Python (like random.randint but for letters)? The range functionality of random.randint would be nice but having a generator that just outputs a random letter would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Simple:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
'j'
```

[`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) returns a string containing the lower case and upper case letters according to the current locale.

[`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) returns a single, random element from a sequence.

Comment: It's actually string.ascii_lowercase or string.ascii_uppercase.

Comment: Often, I need a string of randoms, here's that (after `from string import ascii_letters, digits` and `from random import choice`): `''.join([choice(ascii_letters + digits) for i in range(32)])`

Comment: @joaquin string.letters is present in python 2.7.7.

Answer (score 86):

```
>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
'g'
```

Comment: This can be lower or uppercase. Not sure if that is what is needed.

Comment: @TaylorLeese, as I have known that there are three options including `ascii_letters`, `ascii_uppercase`, and `ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 51):

```
>>>def random_char(y):
       return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))

>>>print (random_char(5))
>>>fxkea
```

to generate y number of random characters

Comment: also: `''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,5))`

Comment: @Dannid Doesn't `random.sample()` return a *unique* set of values from the input, which is not the same as `random.choice()`?

Comment: Yes, though if you're choosing just one letter that doesn't make a difference Furthermore, you may want 5 unique letters - the OP didn't specify, and both `random.choice` and `random.randint` return a single value. You can also use `numpy.random.choice` to give a unique set if you add replace=False, like so: `numpy.random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase, size=5, replace=False)`

Comment: Oh, and y is not defined. Be careful about that.

Comment: @colappse y is the argument passed to the function

Comment: @saad okay I understand you

Answer (score 26):

```
>>> import random
>>> import string    
>>> random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
'b'
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use this to get one or more random letter(s)

```
import random
import string
random.seed(10)
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
rand_letters = random.choices(letters,k=5) # where k is the number of required rand_letters

print(rand_letters)

['o', 'l', 'p', 'f', 'v']
```

Comment: @NigelRen what is the distribution of `random.choices` ?

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara `help(random.choices)` states `If the relative weights or cumulative weights are not specified, the selections are made with equal probability.` This would mean, that the distribution is the discrete uniform distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution).

Answer (score 15):

Another way, for completeness:

```
>>> chr(random.randrange(97, 97 + 26))
```

Use the fact that `ascii` 'a' is 97, and there are 26 letters in the alphabet.

When determining the upper and lower bound of the `random.randrange()` function call, remember that `random.randrange()` is exclusive on its upper bound, meaning it will only ever generate an integer up to 1 unit less that the provided value.

Comment: That depends on what alphabet we're talking about ;-)

Comment: shouldn't it be `chr(random.randrange(97, 97 + 26 - 1))`?

Comment: @zhongxiao37 Really, it should be `chr(random.randrange(97, 97 + 26)`. `random.randrange()` is exclusive on its upper bound, meaning that in order to get the whole range of characters `97 - 122`, the argument passed must be `123`.

Comment: @KieranMoynihan Thanks for sharing. I double checked that and you're right. Now I see why `97 + 26` is used.

Answer (score 6):

You can just make a list:

```
import random
list1=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
b=random.randint(0,7)
print(list1[b])
```

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't use any fancy modules but works fine:

```py
    ''.join(chr(random.randrange(65,90)) for i in range(10))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def randchar(a, b):
    return chr(random.randint(ord(a), ord(b)))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import random
def guess_letter():
    return random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Answer (score 3):

And another, if you pefer `numpy` over `random`:

```
import numpy as np
import string
np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
def Random_Alpha():
    l = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    return l[random.randint(0,25)]

print(Random_Alpha())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#*A handy python password generator*
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZvXr.png)

```
 import random
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']
        
    print("Welcome to the Python Password Generator!")
    l= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
    s = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
    n = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))
        
    sequence = random.sample(letters,l)
    num      = random.sample(numbers,n)
    sym      = random.sample(symbols,s)
    sequence.extend(num)
    sequence.extend(sym)
         
    random.shuffle(sequence)
    password = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in sequence])#listToStr 
    print(password)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
map(lambda a : chr(a),  np.random.randint(low=65, high=90, size=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

A summary and improvement of some of the answers.

```py
import numpy as np
n = 5
[chr(i) for i in np.random.randint(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1, n)]
# ['b', 'f', 'r', 'w', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import random

KEY_LEN = 20

def base_str():
    return (string.letters+string.digits)   
def key_gen():
    keylist = [random.choice(base_str()) for i in range(KEY_LEN)]
    return ("".join(keylist))
```

You can get random strings like this:

```
g9CtUljUWD9wtk1z07iF
ndPbI1DDn6UvHSQoDMtd
klMFY3pTYNVWsNJ6cs34
Qgr7OEalfhXllcFDGh2l
```

Comment: 1. With Python3, it would be `string.ascii_letters` 2. You can save the list comprehension by using `keylist = random.choices(base_str(), k=KEY_LEN)` 3. Why having `base_str` as a function and not a `base_str = string.ascii_letters+string.digits`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_key(key_len):
    key = ''
    valid_characters_list = string.letters + string.digits
    for i in range(key_len):
        character = choice(valid_characters_list)
        key = key + character
    return key

def create_key_list(key_num):
    keys = []
    for i in range(key_num):
        key = create_key(key_len)
        if key not in keys:
            keys.append(key)
    return keys
```

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers are correct, if you are looking for random characters of various types (i.e. alphanumeric and special characters) then here is an script that I created to demonstrate various types of creating random functions, it has three functions one for numbers, alpha- characters and special characters. The script simply generates passwords and is just an example to demonstrate various ways of generating random characters.

```
import string
import random
import sys

#make sure it's 3.7 or above
print(sys.version)

def create_str(str_length):
    return random.sample(string.ascii_letters, str_length)

def create_num(num_length):
    digits = []
    for i in range(num_length):
        digits.append(str(random.randint(1, 100)))

    return digits

def create_special_chars(special_length):
    stringSpecial = []
    for i in range(special_length):
        stringSpecial.append(random.choice('!$%&()*+,-.:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~'))

    return stringSpecial

print("how many characters would you like to use ? (DO NOT USE LESS THAN 8)")
str_cnt = input()
print("how many digits would you like to use ? (DO NOT USE LESS THAN 2)")
num_cnt = input()
print("how many special characters would you like to use ? (DO NOT USE LESS THAN 1)")
s_chars_cnt = input()
password_values = create_str(int(str_cnt)) +create_num(int(num_cnt)) + create_special_chars(int(s_chars_cnt))

#shuffle/mix the values
random.shuffle(password_values)

print("generated password is: ")
print(''.join(password_values))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Example of generating letters and numbers together

```
import random
import string

for_seed = random.randint(1,1000)
random.seed(for_seed)

def create_alphanumerical_randomly(n):
    
    my_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    my_rand_letters = random.choices(my_letters, k=n)

    my_string = ""
    for letter in my_rand_letters:
        my_string += letter

    return my_string + str(for_seed)

my_func = create_alphanumerical_randomly(3)
print(my_func)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

well, this is my answer! It works well. Just put the number of random letters you want in 'number'... (Python 3)

```
import random

def key_gen():
    keylist = random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    return keylist

number = 0
list_item = ''
while number < 20:
    number = number + 1
    list_item = list_item + key_gen()

print(list_item)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import string
import random

def random_char(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits+li) for x in range(y))
no=int(input("Enter the number of character for your password=  "))
li = random.choice('!@#$%^*&( )_+}{')
print(random_char(no)+li)
```

Answer (score -2):

My overly complicated piece of code:

```
import random

letter = (random.randint(1,26))
if letter == 1:
   print ('a')
elif letter == 2:
    print ('b')
elif letter == 3:
    print ('c')
elif letter == 4:
    print ('d')
elif letter == 5:
    print ('e')
elif letter == 6:
    print ('f')
elif letter == 7:
    print ('g')
elif letter == 8:
    print ('h')
elif letter == 9:
    print ('i')
elif letter == 10:
    print ('j')
elif letter == 11:
    print ('k')
elif letter == 12:
    print ('l')
elif letter == 13:
    print ('m')
elif letter == 14:
    print ('n')
elif letter == 15:
    print ('o')
elif letter == 16:
    print ('p')
elif letter == 17:
    print ('q')
elif letter == 18:
    print ('r')
elif letter == 19:
    print ('s')
elif letter == 20:
    print ('t')
elif letter == 21:
    print ('u')
elif letter == 22:
    print ('v')
elif letter == 23:
    print ('w')
elif letter == 24:
    print ('x')
elif letter == 25:
    print ('y')
elif letter == 26:
    print ('z')
```

It basically generates a random number out of 26 and then converts into its corresponding letter. This could defiantly be improved but I am only a beginner and I am proud of this piece of code.

Comment: your answer needs improvement and is not very functional.

Comment: in your case you can simply do `print(chr(96 + letter))`, no `if`-`elif` hell is needed

Comment: This is `if-else` hell, It is not a good practice

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this can help you:

```
import random
for a in range(64,90):
    h = random.randint(64, a)
    e += chr(h)
print e
```

Comment: Why are you iterating between 64 and 90? Why not just go from 0 to 26, and offset a? This answer is quite poor, the output hardly random: `@AAADCCEHFGJLDJF@EHFMHKWUR`

Answer (score -6):

Place a python on the keyboard and let him roll over the letters until you find your preferd random combo                  Just kidding!

```
import string #This was a design above but failed to print. I remodled it.
import random
irandom = random.choice(string.ascii_letters) 
print irandom
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this is a good answer it is _identical_ to the already posted and accepted answer by @MarkRushakoff, answered two years ago. Please review the answers before you post so we can keep the signal to noise ratio down.