# How to generate random word from a set of characters in python

Tags: python

I am looking to generate a random word list from a set of characters in python.
Problem here:-

It is Generating like:-
aaaaaa
aaaaab
aaaaac
...... So on

I want to add random function so it generate same length with randomization of alphabets it has like:-
a15bef
f45acd
9bbac0
...... So on

Look With same length but random.

How to add random function to it?

```
#Code
import itertools

chrs = 'abcdef0123456789' # Change your required characters here
n = 6 # Change your word length here

for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=n):
   print(''.join(xs))
```

---

please help me to solve it.

Comment: Raj - asked & answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823316/generate-a-random-letter-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random letter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823316/generate-a-random-letter-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` will generate all the possible values. Instead, what you want is to pick `n` random characters from `chrs` and concatenate them:

```
import random

chrs = 'abcdef0123456789' # Change your required characters here
n = 6 # Change your word length here

print(''.join(random.choices(chrs, k=5)))
```

Comment: Very good suggested and its working without itertools and consume less memory means faster work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `random.choice`:

```
import random
chrs = 'abcdef0123456789'
n = 6
result = ''.join(random.choice(chrs) for _ in range(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(random.choice(‘abcdef0123456789’) for _ in range(N))
```

A cryptographical more secure option is here, below example will generate random string using all undercase alphabets and digits

```
''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(N))
```

Comment: it says - NameError: name 'string' is not defined

Comment: We import string, a module that contains sequences of common ASCII characters, and random, a module that deals with random generation

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this

```
import random
def generateAWord (length):
    i = 0
    result = ""
    while i < length:
        letter = chr(33 + int(93 * random.random()))
        result += letter
        i +=1
    return result
```

33 in inside chr is the first ascii decimal that you want( 33 represent {!}).
random.random() return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0] so it times that 0.0 - 1.0 by 93 for example 0.1732*93 will result 16,1076 (and it cast that to int, so it will end as 16). So 93 represent the max result from the starting ascii decimal that you want(in this case 33) until the max ascii decimal that you want(in this case 33+93 is 126 which is {~} in ascii decimal).

Then chr will convert that result to char.