# Is it possible to upload to Blobstore using bulkloader

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, bulkloader

Does anyone know if it's possible to use bulkloader to push data into GAE Blobstore?

I have few 100,000 tile images I need to push to my Google App.

At present I'm slowly pushing them to Datastore (seems incredibly slow as keeps "backing off" due to errors). I assume the Blobstore will probably be more efficient for serving my tiles back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the bulkloader doesn't currently have any built-in support for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that bulkloader can just upload images. It uploads data from backup files that was downloaded by itself.

If you have 100K images I'd white a script to upload all of them. Looks like you do it manualy at the moment.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script) the question about how to upload files from python script.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for that - might give me a different avenue to try! BTW: Uploading files (blobs) to Datastore via bulkloader is possible. You just need to write some handlers to process the files.

Answer (score 0):

[You can follow the simple guideline to write a small python script to upload your files to blobstore.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob)

Mainly,

> Applications can use the Blobstore to accept large files as uploads from users and to serve those files.

So, Blobstore is expected to accept big size user data that can be uploaded over a single http connection. It is not meant to upload bulk number of files/data from admin console. At least for now there is no such feature.