# POSTing file to Jenkins fails

Tags: python, http-post, jenkins, multipartform-data

I'm trying to POST a file to Jenkins from Python, via multipart/form-data. The request body looks like this:

```
--===============1849003312==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: file; name="file0"; filename="meta.xml"

PHhtbD4NCjwveG1sPg0K

--===============1849003312==--
```

This causes Jenkins to raise an exception on its end however, the most relevant bits of which follow:

```
Exception: <br>Stacktrace: <pre>org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly
   at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:381)
   at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
   at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.parseMultipartFormData(RequestImpl.java:767)
   at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getSubmittedForm(RequestImpl.java:782)
```

What's wrong with my POST request?

**EDIT:**
The request headers are as follows:

Content-Type:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary="===============1849003312=="
```

MIME-Version:

```
1.0
```

Comment: What about `Content-Type` header of the POST request? Please post its value as well, it is important.

Comment: The boundary in the `Content-Type` header doesn't match the boundary used in the POST body.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant Oops, that's because it's regenerated for each run. I'll update them both.

Comment: Can you post the complete code for creating the request?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Content-Disposition: file;` should be replaced with `Content-Disposition: attachment;`. The source code of [FileUploadBase](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/fileupload/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.java?view=markup) does not mention "file", and [RFC 2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) does not list "file" as a value for content-disposition.

Comment: I tried changing 'file' to 'attachment' for Content-Disposition, it made no difference actually (the same exception occurs). Looking at the FileUploadBase.java source also, it doesn't look like the content disposition matters regarding the exception being thrown.