# How to trigger authenticated Jenkins job with file parameter using standard Python library

Tags: python, rest, post, jenkins, pycurl

We are currently triggering Jenkins jobs from a Python script with the help of PycURL. We would like, however, to get rid of the PycURL dependency, but have had little success so far. What makes our scenario more complicated is that we need to post a file as a parameter. Our current PycURL logic for posting the request looks as follows:

```
url = "https://myjenkins/job/myjob/build"
with contextlib.closing(pycurl.Curl()) as curl:
    curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "myuser:mypassword")
    curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, False)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.FAILONERROR, True)
    data = [
            ("name", "integration.xml"),
            ("file0", (pycurl.FORM_FILE, "integration.xml")),
            ("json", "{'parameter': [{'name': 'integration.xml', 'file': 'file0'}]}"),
            ("Submit", "Build"),
            ]
    curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, data)
    try:
        curl.perform()
    except pycurl.error, err:
        raise JenkinsTriggerError(curl.errstr())
```

How can we replace this with facilities from the standard Python library?

We've tried before, but had to give up as we could not see how to upload files successfully, as you can see from [my question on that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078561/posting-file-to-jenkins-fails=).

Comment: You seem to be using `https`. Beware that `httplib` and `urllib2` don't verify the server certificate when connecting to an HTTPS website (see official documentation), so it won't be able to establish the connection securely. (You can work around this by wrapping the `httplib` connection using the `ssl` module.)

Comment: If you look at my code, you'll see that I'm telling cURL to ignore HTTPS certificate :) It's an intranet site, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Why you wish to use urllib2/httplib over pycURL?

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Because pycURL is a dependency I'd rather avoid.

Comment: pycURL is based on libcurl (pure C code) which has proven better performance and stability over urllib and httplib. Moreover, every linux machine comes with cURL while pycURL is just a single api code to that cURL.

Comment: @dragosrsupercool It's still a (too) heavy dependency

Comment: @aknuds1: too heavy? how? Can u elaborate ur observation? I m the new admin of pycURL and can ensure some solution in the next release we are planning for next month.. .

Comment: @dragosrsupercool We have to build/install both that and cURL manually on Windows

Comment: @aknuds1: hw abt an exe file ? one click installation fr windows?

Comment: @dragosrsupercool That would definitely be an improvement. I guess automatic installation via EasyInstall wouldn't be feasible (due to the libcurl dependency)?

Comment: lemme discuss if we can include libcurl with pycurl within a single package.. .

Comment: @aknuds1: any updates? Can you post code (maybe what you had in that other question)?

Comment: @TryPyPy See my answer, that's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution, using the [requests](http://python-requests.org) and [urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3) libraries. Not entirely standard, but more lightweight than the PycURL dependency. It should be possible to do this directly with requests (avoiding the urllib3 part), but I ran into a bug.

```
import urllib3, requests, json

url = "https://myjenkins.com/job/myjob"

params = {"parameter": [
    {"name": "integration.xml", "file": "file0"},
    ]}
with open("integration.xml", "rb") as f:
    file_data = f.read()
data, content_type = urllib3.encode_multipart_formdata([
    ("file0", (f.name, file_data)),
    ("json", json.dumps(params)),
    ("Submit", "Build"),
    ])
resp = requests.post(url, auth=("myuser", "mypassword"), data=data,
        headers={"content-type": content_type}, verify=False)
resp.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: So if the build requires a token, it would be added along with the parameters? I tried that and it doesn't seem to build

Comment: * doesn't seem to build with the parameter being set

Comment: @Joiya550 You should replicate how tokens are normally sent (ie. In the browser).

Answer (score 10):

We can do it with the help of requests library only.

```
import requests

payload = ( ('file0', open("FILE_LOCATION_ON_LOCAL_MACHINE", "rb")), 
            ('json', '{ "parameter": [ { 
                                         "name":"FILE_LOCATION_AS_SET_IN_JENKINS", 
                                         "file":"file0" }]}' ))

resp = requests.post("JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build", 
                   auth=('username','password'), 
                   headers={"Jenkins-Crumb":"9e1cf46405223fb634323442a55f4412"}, 
                   files=payload )
```

Jekins-Crumb if required can be obtained using:

```
requests.get('http://username:password@JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
```

Comment: The Jenkins Crumb isn't needed if an API token is used in place of the user's password

Comment: Also it seems like you would need to call `read(...)` in addition to `open(..., "rb"))`. Otherwise a zero-byte file would be transferred to your Jenkins workspace. aknuds1's answer below calls both functions on the uploaded file.

Answer (score 6):

If you are familiar with python, then you can use the jenkins REST APT python wrapper provided by the official site. [see this link](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).

Trigger a build is unbelievably easy by using this python wrapper. Here is my example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jenkins

if __name == "main":
    j = jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_server_url, username="youruserid", password="yourtoken")
    j.build_job(yourjobname,{'param1': 'test value 1', 'param2': 'test value 2'},
                    {'token': "yourtoken"})
```

For those who don't know where to find the token, here is how:

> login to jenkins -> click your userid from the top of the webpage ->
>   Configure ->Show API Token...

Enjoy it.

Comment: It doesn't include a file parameter however.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it can look something like this:

```
url = "https://myjenkins/job/myjob/build"
req = urllib2.Request(url)

auth = 'Basic ' + base64.urlsafe_b64encode("myuser:mypassword")
req.add_header('Authorization', auth)

with open("integration.xml", "r") as f:
  file0 = f.read()
  data = {
            "name": "integration.xml",
            "file0": file0,
            "json": "{'parameter': [{'name': 'integration.xml', 'file': 'file0'}]}",
            "Submit": "Build"
         }
  req.add_data(urllib.urlencode(data))

urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Sorry, I don't have installed Jenkins around to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar version to aknuds1 answer where `test_result` is the xml string:

```
j_string = "{'parameter': [{'name': 'integration_tests.xml', 'file': 'someFileKey0'}]}"
data = {
          "name": "integration_tests.xml",
          "json": j_string, 
        }
for xml_string in tests.values():
    post_form_result = requests.post('http://jenkins/job/deployment_tests/build',
                                     data=data,
                                     files={'someFileKey0': xml_string})
    print(post_form_result.status_code)
```

Taking a guess, additional parameters would be passed in as part of the json string array, or additional files, etc. Let me know if this is the case, also, if I find out, i'll update this answer. This solution worked nicely to trigger JUnit tests.

Version:

```
master* $ pip show requests                                                                                                                                                                      [21:45:05]
Name: requests
Version: 2.12.3
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

(2024.01) Let me provide the best solution so far after my eniter day of try and error.

- Python 3.8.11
- Jenkins 2.426.2

[image]

```
import requests

ENDPOINT = 'https://$JENKINS_SERVICE/job/$JENKINS_JOB'
AUTH = ('johndow', 'johndowpwd')

def post_build():
    with open('example.txt', 'rb') as fs:
        r = requests.post(f'{ENDPOINT}/buildWithParameters',
                          auth=AUTH,
                          files={'hey.txt': fs},
                          params={'HI': 'abc', 'HELLO': 'xyz'})
    r.raise_for_status()
```

Note that file close must be stated, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396494/8013269

Answer (score -1):

Another Alternative that I used :

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://myjenkins/job/myjob/build"
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
resp = requests.post(url, params=payload, auth=("username", "password"),verify=False)
json_data = json.loads(resp.text)
```

For more details you can refer :[Make a Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: @aknuds1 Improved answer to post request with parameters. Hope this will resolve your question.

Comment: Does it show how to post a file however? Take a look at my question and answer for reference.

Comment: Yes, when you print json_data you can retrieve response text. Try once.. you will find output.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. The question is how to post a file to Jenkins, my answer handles this.