# How to start a parametrized jenkins job with a file parameter using python

Tags: file, parameters, build, jobs

Scenario:
I want to start a jenkins job with file parameters, using python to trigger the job.

Using

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins

J = Jenkins('http://localhost:8080')

params = {'VERSION': '1.2.3', 'PYTHON_VER': '2.7'}

J.build_job('foo', params)
```

works for string parameters, but how do I use this if I need a file parameter?

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: i am not clear with file parameter, do you want to run jenkins with file as parameter or what

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can build a job with parameters...These parameters, could be Boolean, Choice, String, Text parameters, etc...And there is also an option files parameter. If you choose this one, you can select and upload a file on the jenkins web interface.
My question is, how to solve this with python, similar to my example above.

Comment: refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77824723/8013269

Answer (score 1):

Yes @markus-m you are right that with Build Parameter plugin you can build a job with file as a parameter.You can provide this file to browser and Jenkins will run your job accrodingly, However please find below my comments.

The file you are passing as an argument must be placed in your Jenkins workspace so that Jenkins can access and run this file. The same file name can also be accessed with Jenkins environment variables.

For your scenario, you have two solutions

1. Copy the file that you want to pass as parameter to Jenkins Workspace, so that when you run your job with file location, Jenkins will upload the file and Run accrodingly.
2. you can access Jenkins with Remote API's so that you can run CURL Command and pass file as parameter.

Comment: I know about the possibility to use curl, but I can't use it, for more than just one reason. My question is, if it is possible, using jenkinsapi plugin for python. I can imagine that it would work with file streams, something similar like f = open (path_to_file, "rb") etc.

Comment: @markus-m yes .. You can. I have done it way back with php where i have used jenkins api to do the same. However now i cannot commit if its possible or not.