# How to POST a file in Python mechanize, but without any form?

Tags: python, file-upload, mechanize

How can I make POST request with a file in Python mechanize, but without any existing form, I just need to POST a file "out of the blue". There are some examples of file upload on stackoverflow but all relate to attaching a file in a form.

I just need to generate a POST request with headers like:

```
Content-Length: 218853
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Cookie: some-cookie-data
```

And in the POST data just the contents of a file from disk.

Cookies in the browser session need to be preserved, and I need to read back and process the response, which will be some `Content-Type text/plain;` with some JSON.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
You said you were looking for a mechanize example.  I'm not a mechanize user, but it does support the entire urllib2 API.  So this SO answer will be of assistance: [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script)

When you create a post you're making an HTTP transaction as such:

```
POST /path/to/script HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: UserAgent/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 7 

hello=world
```

So you're always sending in a "form" since that's how the post request receives data.

So, what you'd want to do is figure out however the script you're POSTing to is expecting it's data (the `name` attribute of the form is usually the key necessary for the key=value paring) and then just create your post request.

Make sure you're a using the correct encoding (multipart mime) and you're calculating the correct Content-Length for the header.

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens I happened to have mechanize code open to do this.

```
  # Mechanize
  from mechanize import Browser, urlopen, Request

  # Submit it!
  image_file    = open(image_filename)
  image_data    = image_file.read()

  request       = Request(url, image_data, {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})

  response      = urlopen(request)
```

P.S. LOL, I realize I blogged about this a long time ago:

http://theremichaelwilson.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/posting-a-file-with-mechanize-and-python/