# python code to submit spoj submissions

Tags: python, submit

I was trying to submit my solutions all through a simple python code which takes my username,password, filename, language choice and problem code to submit the solution to spoj on my behalf.

I've gone thus so far,

```
import httplib,urllib
import urllib2
params=urllib.urlencode({'login_user':'username','password':'yourpassword','lang':'C (gcc 4.3.2)','problemcode':'TEST','subm_file':'/home/mj/code/uu.c'})
headers={"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
req=urllib2.Request("http://www.spoj.com/submit/",params)
thepage=urllib2.urlopen(req)
data=thepage.read()
newf=open("wer.html","w")
newf.write(data)
newf.close()`
```

I am expecting "Solution Submitted" to be displayed but instead I get Authorisation Required. But when I try just to login, it does.

Is there a way to enter the Submission after logging in ie the POST method which i am using shoul resume at the page where it logged in successfully, in other words, is there a way in python to "remember" that "I have logged in successfully, now let me submit the problem" So that no "Authorisation Required" prompt is seen.

Comment: there is a python library called mechanize you may like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method for file submission is incorrect. You're passing a string with the filename, not the actual file as your parameter for `subm_file`. You need to POST contents of the file.

I personally use `poster` to POST files: http://atlee.ca/software/poster/

Here's a related SO question: [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script)

Also, looking at the source, I think you want to POST it to `http://www.spoj.com/submit/complete/`, not `.../submit/`. `.../submit/` is the action of the form for the login on the left-hand side. `.../submit/complete/` is the action of the form for submitting the code.

Comment: yes, I want it to submit it to .../submit/complete but i am unable to do so. It says authorisation required meaning to say that it forgets that i am logged in. please tell how to remember that i am logged in so i can proceed with the submission????

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but the way I'd do it is I'd POST the login details to `/submit/` and store the cookies. Then I'd send the cookies with my code submission to `/submit/complete/`

Comment: I don't get it. I coded it in 5 minutes. I didn't even need to use cookies.. just what I mentioned in my solution.

**EDIT:** My bad. I've made one more change. For C (gcc 4.3.2), you'll have to use `'lang':'11'` since the value won't be the string, but the assigned value.

Comment: import httplib,urllib
import urllib2
import poster
import cookielib
opener = poster.streaminghttp.register_openers()
opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
params = {'file': open("/home/mj/code/uu.c", "rb"),'login_user':'name','password':'223021','lang':'11','problemcode':'TEST'}
datagen, headers = poster.encode.multipart_encode(params)
upload_url="https://www.spoj.com/submit/complete"
request = urllib2.Request(upload_url, datagen, headers)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
page=result.read()
print page

Comment: is the above code what ur refereing too. it doesnt work. Check it for urself. it does not work

Comment: Here's my code. I didn't need to use cookiejar, since, as you mentioned, the username and password can be POSTed as well. http://pastie.org/5572405

Comment: urllib2 needs `http://www` as the start. End with `/`. Your url is incomplete. Also, the file goes to `subm_file` not `file`

Comment: Thanx a lot shashwat :D your code is working, but what's the use of register openers which i was missing?

Comment: http://atlee.ca/software/poster/ <- Poster Documentation; It mentions that register_openers() registers the streaming http handles with urllib2, to override its default handlers

Answer (score 0):

Your `params` are not encoded using `Content-type` `"multipart/form-data"`. I've tried sending the request using `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` content type instead and it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import webbrowser
from netrc import netrc
from urllib import urlencode, quote
from urllib2 import urlopen

user, _, password = netrc().authenticators('spoj.com')  # read from ~/.netrc
r = urlopen("https://www.spoj.com/submit/complete/",  # no certificate test
            data=urlencode(dict(
            login_user=user,
            password=password,
            problemcode="TEST",  # problem id
            lang="116",  # Python 3 (see languages below)
            submit="Send",
            file="for s in iter(input, '42'): print(s)")))
m = re.search(r'"newSubmissionId" value="(\d+)"/>', r.read())  # XXX dirty
print("submission id %d" % int(m.group(1)))
webbrowser.open("https://www.spoj.com/status/%s/" % quote(user))
```

#### Languages

```
{
    "7": "ADA 95 (gnat 4.3.2)",
    "13": "Assembler (nasm 2.03.01)",
    "104": "Awk (gawk-3.1.6)",
    "28": "Bash (bash-4.0.37)",
    "12": "Brainf**k (bff 1.0.3.1)",
    "11": "C (gcc 4.3.2)",
    "27": "C# (gmcs 2.0.1)",
    "41": "C++ (g++ 4.3.2)",
    "1": "C++ (g++ 4.0.0-8)",
    "34": "C99 strict (gcc 4.3.2)",
    "14": "Clips (clips 6.24)",
    "111": "Clojure (clojure 1.1.0)",
    "31": "Common Lisp (sbcl 1.0.18)",
    "32": "Common Lisp (clisp 2.44.1)",
    "20": "D (gdc 4.1.3)",
    "36": "Erlang (erl 5.6.3)",
    "124": "F# (fsharp 2.0.0)",
    "5": "Fortran 95 (gfortran 4.3.2)",
    "114": "Go (gc 2010-07-14)",
    "21": "Haskell (ghc 6.10.4)",
    "16": "Icon (iconc 9.4.3)",
    "9": "Intercal (ick 0.28-4)",
    "24": "JAR (JavaSE 6)",
    "10": "Java (JavaSE 6)",
    "35": "JavaScript (rhino 1.7R1-2)",
    "26": "Lua (luac 5.1.3)",
    "30": "Nemerle (ncc 0.9.3)",
    "25": "Nice (nicec 0.9.6)",
    "56": "Node.js (0.8.11)",
    "8": "Ocaml (ocamlopt 3.10.2)",
    "22": "Pascal (fpc 2.2.4)",
    "2": "Pascal (gpc 20070904)",
    "3": "Perl (perl 5.12.1)",
    "54": "Perl 6 (rakudo-2010.08)",
    "29": "PHP (php 5.2.6)",
    "19": "Pike (pike 7.6.112)",
    "15": "Prolog (swipl 5.6.58)",
    "4": "Python (python 2.7)",
    "116": "Python 3 (python 3.2.3)",
    "126": "Python 3 nbc (python 3.2.3 nbc)",
    "17": "Ruby (ruby 1.9.3)",
    "39": "Scala (scala 2.8.0)",
    "33": "Scheme (guile 1.8.5)",
    "18": "Scheme (stalin 0.11)",
    "46": "Sed (sed-4.2)",
    "23": "Smalltalk (gst 3.0.3)",
    "38": "Tcl (tclsh 8.5.3)",
    "62": "Text (plain text)",
    "6": "Whitespace (wspace 0.3)",
}
```

Comment: Your solution is specific for the TEST problem. I think OP wants a general solution.

Comment: @shashwat: The OP's problem is the incorrect http request. The code above works for any spoj problem if you provide appropriate `problemcode`, `lang`, and `file` that are specific for each solution.