# What is the equivalent of HTTP request using "curl ... --data-binary ..." in Python's requests package?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, multipartform-data

What is the equivalent of HTTP request using "curl ... --data-binary ..." in Python's requests package? The HTTP request's 'Content-Type' is 'multipart/form-data; boundary=...'.

Comment: Hi, possible duplicate question [python binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365027/python-post-binary-data).

Comment: Also, check out [this cool website that transforms curl commands into python code](https://curl.trillworks.com/)