# how to use curl with -u in python request

Tags: python, curl, request

I am trying to convert a curl request to python request, but i have problem to convert -u .

```
 curl -X POST \
   -u "apikey:yourKey" \
   --header "Content-Type: audio/wav" \
   --data-binary "@path" \
   "https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=de-DE_BroadbandModel
```

My solution:

```
import requests
data = "path"
url = 'https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=de-DE_BroadbandModel'
#payload = open("request.json")
headers = {'content-type': 'audio/wav', 'username': "apikey=yourkey" }
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Edit:

```
 import requests
    data = "path"
    url = 'https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=de-DE_BroadbandModel'
    #payload = open("request.json")
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'audio/wav'}
    #r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print requests.post(url, verify=False, headers=headers, data=data, auth=('apikey', "key"))
```

now i get

> Response [400]

(the curl cmd is working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, auth=(apiKey, yourApiKey))
```

-u is short for --user which is used for server authentication [see here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u), also look into [Basic authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) for requests library.

Edit: You need to read the file  (specified in `--data-binary "@path"`) first before passing it in `requests.post`. I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365027/python-post-binary-data) link helps