# How to post a Json with a base64 file using python request?

Tags: python, django, api, request

Right now I am programming an API with python, and I have the following problem:
I have to POST the following JSON to an url:

```
prescription = {
"Name": “file_name", # This is a string
"Body" : "xxx",# (File in base64 format)
"ParentId" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", # This is a string
"ContentType" : "xxxxx/xxx" # This is a string
}
```

But when I try to do the following request:

```
requests.post(url, prescription)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

How can I make a request for posting that JSON? Is it even possible?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
Using

```
"Body" : "xxx.decode("utf-8")"
```

worked, thanks for the help

Comment: Try `"Body" : "xxx.decode("utf-8")",`

Comment: please take look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365027/python-post-binary-data its similar what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import base64
import requests

with open("your/file", "rb") as file:
    b64_file_content= base64.b64encode(file.read())

prescription = {
    "Name": "file_name",  # This is a string
    "Body": b64_file_content.decode("ascii"),  # (File in base64 format)
    "ParentId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  # This is a string
    "ContentType": "xxxxx/xxx",  # This is a string
}

requests.post("https://somewhere.world", prescription)
```