# Image Uploading Script in Python

Tags: python, image, uploading

I was trying to make an image uploading script for Postimage.org.
I tried searching for an API but it seems that there is not any available.  Can anyone help me how to make this script ? I don't have any idea how to make the uploading proccess?  I think that something that i should do is open the image file in read binary mode ("rb").
Anyway i am waiting for your suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should think about what happens when you press the upload button on the website. What your script could do is mimic this functionality, because essentially all it's triggering is a POST request to the web server with the specified information in the form and the image file data. You can initiate HTTP requests (e.g. GET, POST, etc.) using a library such as Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

However, as this seems to have been discussed before, I will instead point you in the right direction: [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script)

Comment: Could not get it working.  
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
url = "http://postimage.org"
with open("image.png","rb") as f:
    to_post = f.read()
data = {"content":to_post}
r = requests.post(url,data)

Comment: You will need to adapt the code to work with the image host. There most likely will be some form-encoded data that needs to be sent alongside the image data. You can see on the website that it has fields for image size, adult content, etc. This is image host specific, so you will need to look into what the website wants in a POST request. As there is no API or anything, you'll have your work cut out for you, so you'll need to perhaps check out the HTML form code, monitor the HTTP requests, etc.