# How to do bulk upload of images?

Tags: image, quickblox

I need to upload approximately 1,700 images to the Quickblox site but I am not sure how to do this as it seems to upload only one at a time.

Is there a way to do bulk uploads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try do this by writing a script. Here  http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Python you can find example of auth on Python. Next, you need upload your images (consequentially or in parallel - as you wish). Example of uploading images - [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script).

Hope this help you.