# Upload file to server using paste action

Tags: javascript, python, dom-events, flask-wtforms

I have been trying to upload an image file captured from the clipboard of user to a server (web page implemented through Flask). I have the following code so far (almost verbatim lifted from another Stack Overflow post):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// We start by checking if the browser supports the 
// Clipboard object. If not, we need to create a 
// contenteditable element that catches all pasted data 

// Add the paste event listener
console.log("Start");
if (window.addEventListener) {
    console.log("new event listener");
    window.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler);
    }
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    console.log("old event listener");
    window.attachEvent("onpaste", pasteHandler);
    }
console.log("End");
 
/* Handle paste events */
function pasteHandler(e) {
    console.log("in paste handler");
   // We need to check if event.clipboardData is supported (Chrome)
   if (e.clipboardData) {
        console.log("in clip data");
      // Get the items from the clipboard
      var items = e.clipboardData.items;
      if (items) {
         // Loop through all items, looking for any kind of image
         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
                console.log("image exists in clipboard");
               // We need to represent the image as a file,
               var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
               // and use a URL or webkitURL (whichever is available to the browser)
               // to create a temporary URL to the object
               var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
               var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
               var form = document.forms['addbug'];
               var fd = new FormData(form);    
               fd.append('attach',blob);
               console.log("image added to form");
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The part that I am struggling with is saving the captured stream on the server. I am trying to use the following python code to store the file on server:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    print('in submit')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('in post')
        if 'attach' in request.files:
            print('in attach')
            upload_file = request.files['attach']
            print('upload file = '+str(upload_file))
            print(upload_file.filename)
            if allowed_file(upload_file.filename):
                filename =  secure_filename(upload_file.filename)
                upload_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                file_loc = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

What I get with the last print statement is:

```
upload file = <FileStorage: '' ('application/octet-stream')>
```

which sounds like it is a stream not a file. I think that the upload_file.save does not work as it does not recognize the input as a file, but I have no idea how to (maybe) convert the octet-stream data into a readable file. Or maybe I need to read the blob differently instead of using getAsFile()? Any ideas?

Comment: Note, not certain about `python` portions; curious what is purpose of `form` as parameter to `FormData()` constructor at `var fd = new FormData(form);` at `javascript`? Is `blob` a `File` object?

Comment: My best guess is that `var fd = new FormData(form)` loads the existing form data into a Formdata object, which I then try to manipulate using fd.append(...)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example/8542030#8542030