# python requests post file using multipart form parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an API which requires a **multipart/form-data content** to be send in the body in order to *upload a file(image) using POST*. I have chosen to use python's requests module as it's easy for newbies like me.There are two form parameters to pass; one is called file, which should be the actual file data and the other is called file-data, which is a dictionary object as below:

```
    {"param1": param_val,"param2":param_val1}
```

I have seen http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file but it doesn't speak about passing form parameters, i.e as if these parameters were values being passed from within a web form which provides placeholders for the file name and the other parameters. Note that if I pass ordinary parameters to the API call like:

```
    r = requests.post(url, headers= headers,params=params)
```

I would end up sending the parameters after the URL as in *URL?param1=param_val>...etc* which doesn't work in this case. So I basically need a way to send the form parameters mentioned above as **form data of the request**. If I could get some guidance around the syntax of the POST call to make in the scenario it would help a lot-

******edited for more clarity******

The desired HTTP trace of my POST request is as shown below:

```
    POST <application URL>
    Host: <Host server name>
    Authorization: Basic ABCDXXXX
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Postman-Token: XXXXXX-ABACC-XXXXX
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----     

    ------WebKitFormBoundaryXYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-data"

    {"description": "Sample desc","languageCode": "en" }
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryABCXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
    Content-Type: 


    ------WebKitFormBoundaryWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXX--
```

If I use the form:

```
    r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=filedata,files=files)
```

I end up getting an error message '400 199-repeated entities[]' which on closer investigation reveals that the request is trying to unpack the tuples in my **file-data** variable and ends up creating two content boundaries, one for the **description** and other for the **languagecode.** Is there a way I can just make it pass file-data in the form parameters just once as shown above?

******end of edit*******

Thanks in advance-
Regards

Comment: See the duplicate; you specify parameters in `data` and files with the `files` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. I saw the thread you referred but I want to understand the why the API documentation asks me to use <b>Type: multipart/form-data</b>. Is it to specifically enforce that I am passing form data in my content? Do I have to mention the type as a header parameter or is it implicit?

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is the only encoding that can upload files and key-value data in the same request body. See [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4007969)

Comment: @Martijn my problem is still unsolved. I have followed your suggestions but I keep getting the same error. The problem is to unpack the tuples in a way that the API expects and I'm unable to do so. I have raised another related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341737/python-assign-literal-value-of-a-dictionary-to-key-of-another-dictionary). Would you be able to look into and check if you can help? Thanks in advance-

Comment: You already got help there. You can't just post a dictionary in a form field value.

Comment: But my form parameter is of type _string_. I cannot do json.dumps(filedata) as it would then cause it to get unpacked during runtime. The 2nd part of my nested dictionary is expected as a complete value, i.e. `file-data:{"key1":"value1","key2","value2"....}` I tried using `"file-data":"{"key1":"value1","key2","value2"....}"` but requests still doesn't parse it correctly

Comment: Put that on you other question. Make sure you clearly explain what kind of POST you expect to send. If that is meant to be a string, then create a proper string. Escape the quotes or use single quotes around the value.

Comment: For my case, I need to explicitly set a multipart encoded `Content-Type` header.  [send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script/78078518#78078518), [requests-toolbelt multipartform-data-encoder](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/tree/1.0.0?tab=readme-ov-file#multipartform-data-encoder)