# Python requests post a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Using CURL I can post a file like

```
CURL -X POST -d "pxeconfig=`cat boot.txt`" https://ip:8443/tftp/syslinux
```

My file looks like

```
$ cat boot.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I am trying to achieve the same thing using *requests* module in python

```
r=requests.post(url, files={'pxeconfig': open('boot.txt','rb')})
```

When I open the file on server side, the file contains

```
{:filename=>"boot.txt", :type=>nil, :name=>"pxeconfig", 
:tempfile=>#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170405-19742-1cylrpm.txt>, 
:head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pxeconfig\"; 
filename=\"boot.txt\"\r\n"}
```

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your curl request sends the file contents as form data, as opposed to an actual file! You probably want something like

```
with open('boot.txt', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(url, data={'pxeconfig': f.read()})
```

Answer (score 2):

The two actions you are performing are not the same.

In the first: you explicitly read the file using `cat` and pass it to curl instructing it to use it as the value of a header `pxeconfig`.

Whereas, in the second example you are using multipart file uploading which is a completely different thing. The server is supposed to parse the received file in that case.

To obtain the same behavior as the curl command you should do:

```
requests.post(url, data={'pxeconfig': open('file.txt').read()})
```

For contrast the `curl` request if you actually wanted to send the file multipart encoded is like this:

```
curl -F "header=@filepath" url
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('boot.txt', 'rb') as f: r = requests.post(url, files={'boot.txt': f})
```

You would probably want to do something like that, so that the files closes afterwards also.

Check here for more: [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script)

Comment: This is the correct pattern for posting files, but in this case OP wants to post the contents of the file, not the file itself, it seems.