# file upload works with curl and postman but not python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, file-upload, python-requests

I am attempting to upload a CSV file to an API (which gives me very little error info) using python requests library.

(I'm running Python 3.5 and using requests version 2.18.4 on OS X 10.11.6)

This curl command in terminal works fine: `curl -F 'file=@/path/to/file.csv' myurl.com/upload -H "Authorization: TOKEN sometoken"`

A multipart/form-data POST request from Postman also works, but I can't seem to make it work with the python requests library.

I've tried many variations of this request:

```
import requests
headers = {'Authorization': 'TOKEN sometoken', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(myurl, headers=headers, data=f)

## I've also tried data={"file": f}
```

I get a status code of 200, but the response is `{"success": "false"}` (frustratingly unhelpful).

What am I missing in the python request compared to the curl request?

**EDIT:** it seems that the `-F` flag for the `curl` command emulates an HTML form that has been submitted...is there a way to do this with requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `curl` code you're using the `-F` parameter, which submits the data as a multipart message - in other words you're uploading a file.
With `requests` you can post files with the [`files`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) parameter. An example:

```
import requests

headers = {'Authorization': 'TOKEN sometoken'}
data = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}
r = requests.post(myurl, headers=headers, files=data)
```

Note that `requests` creates the Content-Type header automatically, based on the submitted data.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I noticed the `files` param in the docs, but they only mention it [specifically for multiple file uploads at the same time](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files), which threw me off.

Comment: That's the dvanced usage documentation (in case you want to upload multiple files with the same name), and it can be confusing. The example in [quickstart](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) in is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The python `open()` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) returns a file object. This is not what you want to send to the API.
Instead, you can use:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(myurl, headers=headers, data=f.read())
```

Syntax taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246857/python-requests-post-a-file).

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. I wish I could provide more info, but I have absolutely no error info to go on.