# post method with parameters and files in python

Tags: python, python-requests

My code is:

```
headers={"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "multipart/form-data"}
cox = httplib.HTTPConnection("somedomain.com")
params=urllib.urlencode( {'par1':'1','par2':'2'})
cox.request("POST","/cportal/public/api/edit?par3=3&par4=4",params,headers)
```

along two POST parameters par1 and par2, I want to send a file. how can I do that?

Comment: first things first, i always use requests whenever possible. they make it more straight forward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script)

Comment: Thanks Barmar, but this script sends only file, I want to POST file and parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using requests

```
import requests
site = 'site.com'
filename = 'image.jpg'
```

At The Place Of 'Image' , Add The ID Of The Upload File IN The Site:

```
file={'image':(filename, open(filename, 'r'),'multipart/from-data')}
data = {
      "Button" : "Submit" # Button ID on html
}
r = requests.post(site, files=file, data=data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check