# What is the correct way to pass a csv file using requests in python?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

If I wanted to push a csv file to an endpoint in Python, what is the correct way to do this?

```
with open("foo.csv") as f:
  endpoint = 'some-url'
  headers = {}
  r = requests.post(endpoint, ...., headers = headers)
```

What would be the next steps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

it probably depends on the receiving end but a list of lists is a json object, so directly reading the file using `csv` module could work.

```
import csv
with open("foo.csv") as f:
  endpoint = 'some-url'
  cr = csv.reader(f)  # delimiter="," by default
  r = requests.post(endpoint, json = list(cr))
```

or if the csv file has a title, pass a list of dicts

```
import csv
with open("foo.csv") as f:
  endpoint = 'some-url'
  cr = csv.DictReader(f)  # delimiter="," by default
  r = requests.post(endpoint, json = list(cr))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly push your CSV file since `requests` makes it simple to upload multipart encoded files

```py
with open("foo.csv", "rb") as f:
    file_data = {"file": f}
    endpoint = "some-url"
    response = requests.post(endpoint, files=file_data)
```